# Regular expression for redacting multiple values in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to redact some information using regular expression in Javascript. With the below regex I'm able to replace the part of the values.

**EDIT**

Original String:

`mysql --user=USER_NAME --host=DB_HOST --database=SCHEMA -p -e 'SELECT`

Expression:

`text.replace(/(.*--user=)(\s*)([^]*)/, '$1XX$2')`

Output:

`mysql --user=XX`

However, I would like the output to be:

`mysql --user=XX --host=XXXXXX --database=XXXX -p -e 'SELECT`

Could someone help me with the regular expression to achieve this?

Comment: consider using a cli parser

Comment: or use `$3`....

Comment: how do you determine how many `X` you need to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format stays the same with the single space between the key-value parts, the keys start with `--` and there is `XX` in the replacement, you could match the pattern and capture the key value parts in group 1.

```
\bmysql (--\w+=\w+(?: --\w+=\w+)*)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sOqwcN/1)

In the replacement, split on a space and replace the last part after the `=` with XX

```js
const s = "mysql --user=USER_NAME --host=DB_HOST --database=SCHEMA";
const regex = /\bmysql (--[^\s=]+=[^\s=]+(?: --[^\s=]+=[^\s=]+)*)/;
const result = s.replace(
  regex,
  (_, g1) => "mysql " + g1
  .split(' ')
  .map(s => s.split('=')[0] + "=XX")
  .join(' ')
);
console.log(result);
```

---

An example using an infinite quantifier in the lookbehind

(**note** that if this is for security, replacing each char with a single `X` can give away a hint about the length of the string)

```
(?<=\bmysql(?: --[^\s=]+=[^\s=]+)* --[^\s=]+=)[^\s=]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R4xGhN/1)

```js
const s = "mysql --user=USER_NAME --host=DB_HOST --database=SCHEMA";
const regex = /(?<=\bmysql(?: --[^\s=]+=[^\s=]+)* --[^\s=]+=[^\s=]*)[^\s=]/g;
const result = s.replace(regex, "X");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A considerably simpler solution to achieve what you want with just one Regex replace is the following pattern:

```
(?<=--[a-zA-Z0-9]*=)([^ ]*)
```

```js
const pattern = /(?<=--[a-zA-Z0-9]*=)([^ ]*)/g
const command= "mysql --user=USER_NAME --host=DB_HOST --database=SCHEMA"

console.log(command.replace(pattern, "XX"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of `X` doesn't matter, then this is short and sweet:

```js
const str = 'mysql --user=USER_NAME --host=DB_HOST --database=SCHEMA';
const newStr = str.replace(/(?<=--\w+=)\w+/g, 'XX');
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want number of X to match number of characters in the values:

```js
const text = 'mysql --user=USER_NAME --host=DB_HOST --database=SCHEMA';
const regExp = /(?<= --\w+?=[^ ]*)[^ ]/g;

console.log(text.replace(regExp, 'X'));
```